# Fast alternatives for UIBezierPath

Tags: swift, core-graphics, uibezierpath

I'm making app, that can build graphs. 
I'm working with UIBezierPath, and everything was fine until I decided to make it possible to move and scale the graph using gestures.

here's how i'm drawing:

```swift
var isFirstPoint = true
        color.set()
        funcPath.lineWidth = width

        for i in 0...Int(bounds.size.width * contentScaleFactor) {
            let cgX = CGFloat(i) / contentScaleFactor
            let funcX = Double ((cgX - bounds.width / 2) / scale)

            let funcY = function(funcX) * Double(scale)

            guard !funcY.isNaN else { continue }
            let cgY = -( CGFloat(funcY) - bounds.height / 2)

            if isFirstPoint {
                funcPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: cgX, y: cgY))
                isFirstPoint = false
            } else {
                if cgY > max(bounds.size.width, bounds.size.height) * 2 {
                    isFirstPoint = true
                } else {
                    funcPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: cgX, y: cgY) )
                }
            }
        }
funcPath.stroke()
```

is there is a faster way to do it?

Comment: Yes, i have a scale property and in `didSet`  i am calling SetNeedsDisplay()

Comment: I tried to move it by updating x and y coordinates of origin property, that represent center of the view, but it didn't work well, so i decided to postpone this feature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of thoughts:

1. Rebuilding the path for every pixel can be an expensive process. One way to reduce this cost is to reduce the number of data points you render. For example,  if you’re adjusting `scale` and rebuilding the whole path, you might want to use some `step` factor when updating the path mid-gesture, and replace your `for` loop with:

   ```
   let step = 4
   for i in stride(from: 0, through: Int(bounds.size.width * contentScaleFactor), by: step) {
       ...
   }
   ```

   Then, when the gesture ends, you might update the path one more time, with a `step` of `1`.
2. The other way to do this is to *not* update the `scale` and call `setNeedsDisplay` each time, but rather to just update the `transform` of the view. (This can result in super fast behavior when zooming in, but is obviously problematic when zooming out, as portions excluded from the path won’t be rendered.)
3. If you’re testing this, make sure to test release (i.e. optimized) build on physical device. Debug builds, with all of their safety checks, can really slow down the process, which will stand out with something as computationally intensive as this.
4. By the way, it looks like the building of the path is buried in `draw(rect:)`. I’d decouple the building of the `UIBezierPath` from the stroking of the path because while, yes, every time you update the function, you may want to update and draw the path, you definitely don’t want re-build the path every time `draw(rect:)` is called.
5. Once you do that, the `draw(rect:)` might not even be needed any. You might just add a `CAShapeLayer` as sublayer of the view’s layer, set the `strokeColor` and `strokeWidth` of that shape layer, and then update its `path`.

Answer (score 1):

Generally moving and scaling is done by applying transforms to layers. Look at `CAShapeLayer` to hold your path. As the user gestures, apply transforms; then recreate the path when the gesture completes. In more advanced usage, you may recalculate the actual path more often than just when the user stops (such as if they pause without letting go), but these are refinements.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what do you mean saying apply transforms? Should i use `apply(_:)` method of `UIBezierPath`, or `setAffineTransform()` of `CAShapeLayer`?

Comment: `setAffineTransform`

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to describe the translation (pan) and scale as a `CGAffineTransform` then you can apply it to your `UIBezierPath` in one go using [`apply(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibezierpath/1624340-apply).